# How to transfere my code from I7 processor to Xeon processor on (AWS)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, cross-platform

I make some codes on this environment:

a) my laptop with i7 processor;

b) IDE "visual studio"/C/C++

Now, I want to transfere the code on AWS with Xeon E5-2670.

1) Is it possible ?

2) Must i change the configuration on "visual studio" or take the code and make it runs directly on the the Xeon proc ?

3) do you have some references i could follow

Thank for you help and recommendations
Alvaro

Comment: Xeon and i7 are all x86 processors, so they are compatible; what is going to matter is more stuff like you are building an executable on Windows and try to run it on Linux.

Comment: @MatteoItalia VC++ compiler has compilation options for SSE etc so they have to also match, not all binaries it produces are runnable on all x86 processors (even if we skip bitness).

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: every i7 ever produced is 64 bit capable, as the E5; SSE up to SSE3 is standard in the processors built in the last 10+ years; you have to be up to some quite recent stuff (like AVX) to start to see this kind of problems. Also, the default configuration of VC++ projects is quite conservative (it may not even enable SSE by default when building 32 bit), so, unless OP changed random settings he doesn't understand, he should be in the clear.

Comment: @MatteoItalia True, but your statement was just a bit too broad for compatibility being based only on processors being x86. And not even all Core i series CPUs have the same capabilities, so it doesn't need to be very recent stuff to cause issues in some cases. Just being more pedantic :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should run directly, but it might not be as efficient as if it were compiled on the AWS system. I.e. I coded a program optimised for a 4 core 8 thread computer, but when I ran it on my laptop with a 2 core 4 thread processor it nearly crashed it.I can also guess that running the program on a 6 core 12 thread processor would not achieve full efficiency.

If you're talking about the runtime environment (I just remembered that) there is a chance that Visual Studio provides non-standard libraries which you would need to download and/or compile before being able to run the program. E.g. I sent my program to my friend, who was missing a required DLL to run the program.

EDIT (I'm new here, so not enough rep to comment): Usually I just search for the missing DLLs on dll-files.com. I'm not sure about linux though, could be that you have to compile libraries yourself, which I'm not that familiar with.

Comment: Did you find the missing dll ?...i have an equivalent problem now

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have set up the compilation options. If you have not enabled any specific options that allow the compiler to use instructinos not present on the target processor the executable will run. You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/1) to determine what DLLs your executable requires.

The default options in VS C++ projects will produce executables that run on practically any modern x86 processor. By itself your machine's CPU doesn't matter when compiling, only compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

After the try, the execution results in 2 errors:
MSVCP144.dll missing
MSVCP100.dll missing